# Gatsby config file for each page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to use Gatsby for creating the static site. My question is, can I add all metadata in for all page (route) in `gatsby-config.json`?

This is a sample of Gatsby config:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Default Starter',
  },
  plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-react-helmet'],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add any data into `siteMetadata` you want. You can query it via GraphQL then (in your pages/templates/layout) or via a `StaticQuery` (only available in Gatsby v2).

Have a look at the official tutorial:
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/#querying-for-the-site-title

It shows you how to query and use the data in your `gatsby-config.js`.